# Optional dependency on annotation library with runtime retention

Tags: java, sql, annotations, dynamic-linking, jooq

Hell froze over and I'm thinking of adding a dependency to [JSR-305 `@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` annotations](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6244) to the [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) API, e.g. to make guarantees like:

```
public interface Field<T> {
    ...

    // The resulting Condition will never be null
    @Nonnull

    // The argument Field can be null for convenience
    Condition eq(@Nullable Field<T> other);
}
```

Among all the unfortunate options, I'm opting for JSR-305, naturally, because it appears to be the least intrusive dependency, [despite it being dormant](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305). These are my intrusiveness concerns:

- [jOOQ follows a zero-dependency policy](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/08/11/all-libraries-should-follow-a-zero-dependency-policy/)
- If ever there is an exception, a standard should be preferred
- If ever a standard is available, it should be stable

#### My question:

JSR-305 annotations have `@Retention(RUNTIME)` for obvious reasons. This means that by adding such annotations, I would create a compile time dependency on that library. I can live with that.

However, I don't want to require that consumers of the jOOQ API add this dependency on their side to *run* the library. It should be possible to run jOOQ without running into any `NoClassDefFoundError` et al.

I've made the following test:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

class Annotated {
    @Annotation
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("works");
    }
}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface Annotation {}
```

I've then copied the `Annotated.class` out of the project (without the `Annotation.class`) and ran it. It printed "works" as expected.

**Is this guaranteed to work? If yes/no, why?**

Note: I'm aware of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397106/521799), but I'm looking for JLS-style formal proof of this behaviour. Also: I gave a bit more context than strictly needed because perhaps there's another solution.

Comment: Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032946/are-annotation-class-files-needed-in-the-runtime-class-path